# Using lots of regex substitutions to tokenize text

Tags: python, performance, regex, natural-language-processing, cython

I authored a piece of code that was merged into the [`nltk`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/toktok.py) codebase. It is full of regex substitutions:

```
import re
from six import text_type

from nltk.tokenize.api import TokenizerI

class ToktokTokenizer(TokenizerI):
    """
    This is a Python port of the tok-tok.pl from
    https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl

    >>> toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
    >>> text = u'Is 9.5 or 525,600 my favorite number?'
    >>> print (toktok.tokenize(text, return_str=True))
    Is 9.5 or 525,600 my favorite number ?
    >>> text = u'The https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl is a website with/and/or slashes and sort of weird : things'
    >>> print (toktok.tokenize(text, return_str=True))
    The https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl is a website with/and/or slashes and sort of weird : things
    >>> text = u'\xa1This, is a sentence with weird\xbb symbols\u2026 appearing everywhere\xbf'
    >>> expected = u'\xa1 This , is a sentence with weird \xbb symbols \u2026 appearing everywhere \xbf'
    >>> assert toktok.tokenize(text, return_str=True) == expected
    >>> toktok.tokenize(text) == [u'\xa1', u'This', u',', u'is', u'a', u'sentence', u'with', u'weird', u'\xbb', u'symbols', u'\u2026', u'appearing', u'everywhere', u'\xbf']
    True
    """
    # Replace non-breaking spaces with normal spaces.
    NON_BREAKING = re.compile(u"\u00A0"), " "

    # Pad some funky punctuation.
    FUNKY_PUNCT_1 = re.compile(u'([،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟¡%٪°±©®।॥…])'), r" \1 "
    # Pad more funky punctuation.
    FUNKY_PUNCT_2 = re.compile(u'([({\[“‘„‚«‹「『])'), r" \1 "
    # Pad En dash and em dash
    EN_EM_DASHES = re.compile(u'([–—])'), r" \1 "

    # Replace problematic character with numeric character reference.
    AMPERCENT = re.compile('& '), '&amp; '
    TAB = re.compile('\t'), ' &#9; '
    PIPE = re.compile('\|'), ' &#124; '

    # Pad numbers with commas to keep them from further tokenization. 
    COMMA_IN_NUM = re.compile(r'(?<!,)([,،])(?![,\d])'), r' \1 '

    # Just pad problematic (often neurotic) hyphen/single quote, etc.
    PROB_SINGLE_QUOTES = re.compile(r"(['’`])"), r' \1 '
    # Group ` ` stupid quotes ' ' into a single token.
    STUPID_QUOTES_1 = re.compile(r" ` ` "), r" `` "
    STUPID_QUOTES_2 = re.compile(r" ' ' "), r" '' "

    # Don't tokenize period unless it ends the line and that it isn't 
    # preceded by another period, e.g.  
    # "something ..." -> "something ..." 
    # "something." -> "something ." 
    FINAL_PERIOD_1 = re.compile(r"(?<!\.)\.$"), r" ."
    # Don't tokenize period unless it ends the line eg. 
    # " ... stuff." ->  "... stuff ."
    FINAL_PERIOD_2 = re.compile(r"""(?<!\.)\.\s*(["'’»›”]) *$"""), r" . \1"

    # Treat continuous commas as fake German,Czech, etc.: „
    MULTI_COMMAS = re.compile(r'(,{2,})'), r' \1 '
    # Treat continuous dashes as fake en-dash, etc.
    MULTI_DASHES = re.compile(r'(-{2,})'), r' \1 '
    # Treat multiple periods as a thing (eg. ellipsis)
    MULTI_DOTS = re.compile(r'(\.{2,})'), r' \1 '

    # This is the \p{Open_Punctuation} from Perl's perluniprops
    # see http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html
    OPEN_PUNCT = text_type(u'([{\u0f3a\u0f3c\u169b\u201a\u201e\u2045\u207d'
                            u'\u208d\u2329\u2768\u276a\u276c\u276e\u2770\u2772'
                            u'\u2774\u27c5\u27e6\u27e8\u27ea\u27ec\u27ee\u2983'
                            u'\u2985\u2987\u2989\u298b\u298d\u298f\u2991\u2993'
                            u'\u2995\u2997\u29d8\u29da\u29fc\u2e22\u2e24\u2e26'
                            u'\u2e28\u3008\u300a\u300c\u300e\u3010\u3014\u3016'
                            u'\u3018\u301a\u301d\ufd3e\ufe17\ufe35\ufe37\ufe39'
                            u'\ufe3b\ufe3d\ufe3f\ufe41\ufe43\ufe47\ufe59\ufe5b'
                            u'\ufe5d\uff08\uff3b\uff5b\uff5f\uff62')
    # This is the \p{Close_Punctuation} from Perl's perluniprops
    CLOSE_PUNCT = text_type(u')]}\u0f3b\u0f3d\u169c\u2046\u207e\u208e\u232a'
                            u'\u2769\u276b\u276d\u276f\u2771\u2773\u2775\u27c6'
                            u'\u27e7\u27e9\u27eb\u27ed\u27ef\u2984\u2986\u2988'
                            u'\u298a\u298c\u298e\u2990\u2992\u2994\u2996\u2998'
                            u'\u29d9\u29db\u29fd\u2e23\u2e25\u2e27\u2e29\u3009'
                            u'\u300b\u300d\u300f\u3011\u3015\u3017\u3019\u301b'
                            u'\u301e\u301f\ufd3f\ufe18\ufe36\ufe38\ufe3a\ufe3c'
                            u'\ufe3e\ufe40\ufe42\ufe44\ufe48\ufe5a\ufe5c\ufe5e'
                            u'\uff09\uff3d\uff5d\uff60\uff63')
    # This is the \p{Close_Punctuation} from Perl's perluniprops
    CURRENCY_SYM = text_type(u'$\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\u058f\u060b\u09f2\u09f3\u09fb'
                             u'\u0af1\u0bf9\u0e3f\u17db\u20a0\u20a1\u20a2\u20a3'
                             u'\u20a4\u20a5\u20a6\u20a7\u20a8\u20a9\u20aa\u20ab'
                             u'\u20ac\u20ad\u20ae\u20af\u20b0\u20b1\u20b2\u20b3'
                             u'\u20b4\u20b5\u20b6\u20b7\u20b8\u20b9\u20ba\ua838'
                             u'\ufdfc\ufe69\uff04\uffe0\uffe1\uffe5\uffe6')

    # Pad spaces after opening punctuations.
    OPEN_PUNCT_RE = re.compile(u'([{}])'.format(OPEN_PUNCT)), r'\1 '
    # Pad spaces before closing punctuations.
    CLOSE_PUNCT_RE = re.compile(u'([{}])'.format(CLOSE_PUNCT)), r'\1 '
    # Pad spaces after currency symbols.
    CURRENCY_SYM_RE = re.compile(u'([{}])'.format(CURRENCY_SYM)), r'\1 '

    # Use for tokenizing URL-unfriendly characters: [:/?#]
    URL_FOE_1 = re.compile(r':(?!//)'), r' : ' # in perl s{:(?!//)}{ : }g;
    URL_FOE_2 = re.compile(r'\?(?!\S)'), r' ? ' # in perl s{\?(?!\S)}{ ? }g;
    # in perl: m{://} or m{\S+\.\S+/\S+} or s{/}{ / }g;
    URL_FOE_3 = re.compile(r'(:\/\/)[\S+\.\S+\/\S+][\/]'), ' / '
    URL_FOE_4 = re.compile(r' /'), r' / ' # s{ /}{ / }g;

    # Left/Right strip, i.e. remove heading/trailing spaces.
    # These strip regexes should NOT be used,
    # instead use str.lstrip(), str.rstrip() or str.strip() 
    # (They are kept for reference purposes to the original toktok.pl code)  
    LSTRIP = re.compile(r'^ +'), ''
    RSTRIP = re.compile(r'\s+$'),'\n' 
    # Merge multiple spaces.
    ONE_SPACE = re.compile(r' {2,}'), ' '

    TOKTOK_REGEXES = [NON_BREAKING, FUNKY_PUNCT_1, 
                      URL_FOE_1, URL_FOE_2, URL_FOE_3, URL_FOE_4,
                      AMPERCENT, TAB, PIPE,
                      OPEN_PUNCT_RE, CLOSE_PUNCT_RE, 
                      MULTI_COMMAS, COMMA_IN_NUM, FINAL_PERIOD_2,
                      PROB_SINGLE_QUOTES, STUPID_QUOTES_1, STUPID_QUOTES_2,
                      CURRENCY_SYM_RE, EN_EM_DASHES, MULTI_DASHES, MULTI_DOTS,
                      FINAL_PERIOD_1, FINAL_PERIOD_2, ONE_SPACE]

    def tokenize(self, text, return_str=False):
        text = text_type(text) # Converts input string into unicode.
        for regexp, subsitution in self.TOKTOK_REGEXES:
            text = regexp.sub(subsitution, text)
        # Finally, strips heading and trailing spaces
        # and converts output string into unicode.
        text = text_type(text.strip()) 
        return text if return_str else text.split()
```

**Is there a way to make the subtituition faster?** E.g.

- Combine the chain of regexes into one super regex.
- Combine some of the regexes
- Coding it in Cython (but [Cython regexes are slow, no?](http://romankleiner.blogspot.sg/2015/06/cython-and-regular-expressions.html))
- Running the regex substitution in Julia and wrapping Julia code in Python

The use case for the `tokenize()` function usually takes a single input but if the same function is called 1,000,000,000 times, it's rather slow and the GIL is going to lock up the core and process each sentence at a time.

The aim of the question is to ask for ways to speed up a Python code that's made up of regex substitution, esp. when running the `tokenize()` function for 1,000,000,000+ times.

If Cython/Julia or any faster language + wrapper is suggested, it would be good if you give an one regex example of how the regex is written in Cython/Julia/Others and the suggestion on how the wrapper would look like.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Because questions involving someone else's code are off-topic here. See [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4985/84718) for instance, for reasonnings.

Comment: I wrote the code almost from scratch... https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commits/develop/nltk/tokenize/toktok.py (I'm https://github.com/alvations -_-|||) Arguably, perhaps this line had some minor improvement from another contributor: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/550427200c0c47d5b2e9429634fc9a676ae28b54#diff-202be6c8a723cf60948a19f7efbe8fa2R51

Comment: That was not exactly obvious when reading the post that it was you the original author… Retracting my downvote and close cast.

Comment: Sorry about it, partly my fault too, didn't want to turn the questions into a "shameless plug" so I was being a little discrete about it. Just looking for a solution/suggestions to help improve an OSS that I contribute to =)

Comment: Are the sentences mostly short like the examples?

Comment: There are no bounds on how long / short the input string would be but for sanity sake, let's consider 20 words 7 chars per word as the median. So around 140 chars per input string

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but you're essentially compiling all the regexes when module is imported, right ? Why not instead make a dictionary of keyword+regex strings, and then selectively compile them ? Perhaps with use of `re.search()` ? The `LSTRIP` and `RSTRIP` probably should be commented out if they're not used.  Speeding up could be done with use of generator yielding the selective regex string, if you chose that route. Just throwing out a few ideas here as comment

Comment: Cython gives a good speed boost when it can translate your code into pure C, or has access to a well developed C/C++ library.  You won't see much/any speed gain if it makes extensive calls to Python code.

Comment: @hpaulj Cython would provide speedup for native C processes but for Cython regex replacements would it be faster?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think the optimization at import time isn't as significant as the fact that Python could only process one sentence at a time with a single core. So the regex compilation for `LSTRIP` and `RSTRIP` isn't going to cost much but I agree it should eb commented out. Perhaps I'm mistaken but `re.search()` doesn't do the string substitution right? Could you give an example of how the generator would look like; wouldn't the string need to be materialized after each substitution before another `re.sub` ?

Answer (score 6):

## 3x to 4x speedup using str.translate()

Based on a quick test (see below), `str.translate()` is an order of magnitude faster than a regular expression for replacing a single character with another character or short string.  So, use `str.translate()` to take care of most of the substitutions and just use the regular expressions for the few complex patterns.

Preliminary timing test.  Building the table or regex is not part of the timing, just the substitution.

Using translate():

```
table = str.maketrans({c:f"{c} " for c in OPEN_PUNCT})
%timeit OPEN_PUNCT.translate(table)
7.4 µs ± 99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And using re.sub()

```
regex = re.compile('(['+OPEN_PUNCT+'])')
%timeit regex.sub(r'\1 ', OPEN_PUNCT)
109 µs ± 1.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Based on the timing results, I put some of the regexes into str.translate and combined many of the remaining regexes, so now there are only 4 (instead of 24).  I'm not sure what URL_FOE_3 is supposed to match (bases on either the comment or the pattern), so I left that one as is.

Also, `str.split()` already collapses adjacent whitespace, so the ONE_SPACE regex is only needed if `return_str` is True.

Here is the revised code:

```
import re
from six import text_type

from nltk.tokenize.api import TokenizerI


class ToktokTokenizer2(TokenizerI):
    """
    This is a modified verion of a Python port of the tok-tok.pl from
    https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl

    >>> toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
    >>> text = u'Is 9.5 or 525,600 my favorite number?'
    >>> print (toktok.tokenize(text, return_str=True))
    Is 9.5 or 525,600 my favorite number ?
    >>> text = u'The https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl is a website with/and/or slashes and sort of weird : things'
    >>> print (toktok.tokenize(text, return_str=True))
    The https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl is a website with/and/or slashes and sort of weird : things
    >>> text = u'\xa1This, is a sentence with weird\xbb symbols\u2026 appearing everywhere\xbf'
    >>> expected = u'\xa1 This , is a sentence with weird \xbb symbols \u2026 appearing everywhere \xbf'
    >>> assert toktok.tokenize(text, return_str=True) == expected
    >>> toktok.tokenize(text) == [u'\xa1', u'This', u',', u'is', u'a', u'sentence', u'with', u'weird', u'\xbb', u'symbols', u'\u2026', u'appearing', u'everywhere', u'\xbf']
    True
    """

    tabledict = {u"\u00A0":" "}  # Replace non-breaking spaces with normal spaces.


    FUNKY_PUNCT = (
        u'،;؛¿!"\])}»›”؟¡%٪°±©®।॥…'    # Pad some funky punctuation.
        u'({\[“‘„‚«‹「『'                # Pad more funky punctuation.
        u'–—'                          # Pad En dash and em dash
        u"'’`"                         # Just pad problematic (often neurotic) hyphen/single quote, etc.
        )

    tabledict.update((c,f" {c} ") for c in FUNKY_PUNCT)

    # This is the \p{Open_Punctuation} from Perl's perluniprops
    # see http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html
    OPEN_PUNCT = text_type(u'([{\u0f3a\u0f3c\u169b\u201a\u201e\u2045\u207d'
                            u'\u208d\u2329\u2768\u276a\u276c\u276e\u2770\u2772'
                            u'\u2774\u27c5\u27e6\u27e8\u27ea\u27ec\u27ee\u2983'
                            u'\u2985\u2987\u2989\u298b\u298d\u298f\u2991\u2993'
                            u'\u2995\u2997\u29d8\u29da\u29fc\u2e22\u2e24\u2e26'
                            u'\u2e28\u3008\u300a\u300c\u300e\u3010\u3014\u3016'
                            u'\u3018\u301a\u301d\ufd3e\ufe17\ufe35\ufe37\ufe39'
                            u'\ufe3b\ufe3d\ufe3f\ufe41\ufe43\ufe47\ufe59\ufe5b'
                            u'\ufe5d\uff08\uff3b\uff5b\uff5f\uff62')
    tabledict.update((c,f"{c} ") for c in OPEN_PUNCT)

    # This is the \p{Close_Punctuation} from Perl's perluniprops
    CLOSE_PUNCT = text_type(u')]}\u0f3b\u0f3d\u169c\u2046\u207e\u208e\u232a'
                            u'\u2769\u276b\u276d\u276f\u2771\u2773\u2775\u27c6'
                            u'\u27e7\u27e9\u27eb\u27ed\u27ef\u2984\u2986\u2988'
                            u'\u298a\u298c\u298e\u2990\u2992\u2994\u2996\u2998'
                            u'\u29d9\u29db\u29fd\u2e23\u2e25\u2e27\u2e29\u3009'
                            u'\u300b\u300d\u300f\u3011\u3015\u3017\u3019\u301b'
                            u'\u301e\u301f\ufd3f\ufe18\ufe36\ufe38\ufe3a\ufe3c'
                            u'\ufe3e\ufe40\ufe42\ufe44\ufe48\ufe5a\ufe5c\ufe5e'
                            u'\uff09\uff3d\uff5d\uff60\uff63')
    tabledict.update((c,f" {c}") for c in CLOSE_PUNCT)

    # This is the \p{Close_Punctuation} from Perl's perluniprops
    CURRENCY_SYM = text_type(u'$\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\u058f\u060b\u09f2\u09f3\u09fb'
                             u'\u0af1\u0bf9\u0e3f\u17db\u20a0\u20a1\u20a2\u20a3'
                             u'\u20a4\u20a5\u20a6\u20a7\u20a8\u20a9\u20aa\u20ab'
                             u'\u20ac\u20ad\u20ae\u20af\u20b0\u20b1\u20b2\u20b3'
                             u'\u20b4\u20b5\u20b6\u20b7\u20b8\u20b9\u20ba\ua838'
                             u'\ufdfc\ufe69\uff04\uffe0\uffe1\uffe5\uffe6')
    tabledict.update((c,f" {c} ") for c in CURRENCY_SYM)


    # Replace problematic character with numeric character reference.
    AMPERCENT = '&', '&amp; '
    TAB = '\t', ' &#9; '
    PIPE = '|', ' &#124; '
    tabledict.update([AMPERCENT, TAB, PIPE])

    TABLE = str.maketrans(tabledict)

    # Group ` ` stupid quotes ' ' into a single token.
    STUPID_QUOTES = re.compile(r" (['`]) \1 "), r" \1\1 "


    # Don't tokenize period unless it ends the line and that it isn't 
    # preceded by another period, e.g.  
    # "something ..." -> "something ..." 
    # "something." -> "something ." 
    # Don't tokenize period unless it ends the line eg. 
    # " ... stuff." ->  "... stuff ."
    FINAL_PERIOD = re.compile(r"""(?<!\.)\.(?:\s*(["'’»›”]) *)?$"""), r" . \1"

    PAD_BEFORE_AND_AFTER = re.compile(r'''
        ((?<!,)[,،](?![,\d])    # Pad numbers with commas to keep them from further tokenization. 
        |([-.,])\2+             # Treat continuous commas, dashes, or periods as fake German,Czech, etc.fake en-dash, etc. or as a thing (eg. ellipsis)
        |:(?!//)                # : not followed by //
        |\?(?!\S)               # ? not followed by a non-space
        |[ ]/                   # ' /' 
        )        
    ''', re.VERBOSE), r" \1 "

    # in perl: m{://} or m{\S+\.\S+/\S+} or s{/}{ / }g;
    URL_FOE_3 = re.compile(r'(:\/\/)[\S+\.\S+\/\S+][\/]'), ' / '

    ONE_SPACE = re.compile(r' {2,}'), ' '

    TOKTOK_REGEXES = [FINAL_PERIOD, STUPID_QUOTES, PAD_BEFORE_AND_AFTER, URL_FOE_3]

    def tokenize(self, text, return_str=False):
        text = text_type(text) # Converts input string into unicode.

        text = text.translate(self.TABLE)

        for regexp, subsitution in self.TOKTOK_REGEXES:
            text = regexp.sub(subsitution, text)

        if return_str:
            text = self.ONE_SPACE.sub(' ', text)

        # Finally, strips heading and trailing spaces
        # and converts output string into unicode.
        text = text_type(text.strip()) 

        return text if return_str else text.split()
```

#### Some tests

Make sure is has the same results as the original

```
testcases = (u'Is 9.5 or 525,600 my favorite number?',
             u'The https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl is a website with/and/or slashes and sort of weird : things',
             u'\xa1This, is a sentence with weird\xbb symbols\u2026 appearing everywhere\xbf',
             "testing.", "'testing. '  ",
             'a, b', '1,234', 'a-b', 'a--b', 'a ... b', 'a,,,b', 
             'a:b', 'http://example.com/', 'hmm? ', 'h?m', 'invert /signal')

for text in testcases:

    r1 = t1.tokenize(text)
    r2 = t2.tokenize(text)

    if r1 != r2:
        print(f"'{text}' -> '{r1}' != '{r2}'")
```

#### Timing

Original:

```
%%timeit t1 = ToktokTokenizer()
for text in testcases:
    t1.tokenize(text)

320 µs ± 3.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Revised:

```
%%timeit t2 = ToktokTokenizer2()
for text in testcases:
    t2.tokenize(text)

107 µs ± 585 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Any idea why the `str.translate()` is faster than `re.sub()`? Anything that points to some docs?

Comment: I suspect there is less work to do.  For each char in the string, str.translate() looks up and inserts the replacement string.  For the regex, there is the added overhead of a finite state machine to recognize the patterns (even if they are only a single character).

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to make the substitution faster? E.g. ... Combine some of the regexes

Both of (NON_BREAKING, ONE_SPACE) substitute the same replacement expression, as does the triple ({OPEN,CLOSE}_PUNCT_RE, CURRENCY_SYM_RE). This suggests there may be an advantage to combining the two or three regexes. A larger number of regexes use `r' \1 '` as the replacement, so that may yield a larger win.